# Cypress/TypeScript: Passing values to class functions on creation of object

Tags: typescript, cypress

This might be a silly or stupid question, but I'm having trouble finding information about it. It's probably because I'm not using the correct search terms.

I have this class (somewhat simplified/shortened):

```
export class Property {
   id: string = '';
   adresses: string[] = new Array();

   constructor(propertystring: string[]) {
       this.id = propertystring[0];           
   }

   addAdress(adresstring: string) {
       this.adresses.push(adresstring);
   }
}

addPropertyInfo(property: Property) {
    ....
}
```

And I want to be able to do this:

```
addProperty(new Property(['0', 'City', '1', '0']).addAdress('Address string 1'));
```

However - this gives me the error

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Property'
```

I can, of course, do this:

```
let property: Property = new Property(['0', 'City', '1', '0']).addAdress('Address string 1');
property.addAddress('Address string 1');
```

There's something basic I'm missing, I know. But what? It seems that by adding the call to the void method when creating to object, it becomes a void parameter instead of Property.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUoTMWATzgG8AoOSgSwBMAuONGKKgOwHM4BeOAcl4DcFSihpRgGCQyYsOAbQC63OK2AB3OAEEoUFIQAUASiHDEEVjICuCGNH1hc+IjLbtpzV4sOlTlSjAALKjQAOlplBzwCGEIXeQAGBQE-FJTTAF8yU1EaTTEJNH1RcQwPDndZdm9yVP8g0OKCiRCwSzQAovzSyuMMskyyVQ0cKKJ9OV543gAaPgBhKhiZvgBGZcneBUMQnLySwt48rsw4zjXjIA

Comment: Sorry. I simplified it too much. I've corrected  the code. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUoTMWATzgG8AoOSgSwBMAuONGKKgOwHM4BeOAcl4DcFSihpRgGCQyYsOAbQC63OK2AB3OAEEoUFIQAUASiHDEEVjICuCGNH1hc+IjLbtpzV4sOlTlSjAALKjQAOlplBzwCGEIXeQAGBQE-FJTTAF8yU1EaTTEJNH1RcQwPDndZdm9yVP8g0OKCiRCwSzQAovzSyuMMskyyADNLVhsqczgcnCiiAElWQYh7R2jCBmmnGOrffqyplbmFpdUNDdX9OV543gAaPgBhKhjbvgBGF6veBUMQnLySwq8PJdTBxTjvQzGIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let property: Property = new Property(['0', 'City', '1', '0']).addAdress('Address string 1');
```

means that `property` will be assigned the return value of `.addAdress(...)`, which happens to return nothing i.e. `void`

The compiler is complaining that you can't assign the return type `void` to the type `Property`

To use it in the way you wrote, you would have to either: -

1. Return `this` (the object itself) from the `addAdress(...)` method

```
addAdress() {
    this.adresses.push(adresstring);
    return this;
}
```

OR
2. Separate into two steps (as you mentioned)

```
const property: Property = new Property(['0', 'City', '1', '0']);
property.addAdress('Address string 1');
```

Update: w.r.t the example you provided on the TS Playground

```
function addPropertyInfo(property: Property) {    
}

addPropertyInfo(new Property(['0', 'City', '1', '0']).addAdress('Address string 1'));
```

Similar to my answer above, `addPropertyInfo(...)` expects type `Property` and you're providing type `void` to it. You could try to follow one of the two approaches listed above to solve this.

Comment: THAT'S what I was missing! Thanks :-)